# Laravel 4.2 how to determine if model is soft delete or force delete

Tags: laravel, cascading-deletes, soft-delete

This is my code in Invoice model:

```
class Invoice extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = "invoice";
    protected $guarded = ["id"];
    protected $deleted_at = ['deleted_at'];

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        Invoice::deleted(function($invoice) {
            if($invoice->isSoftDelete()) {
                //do in case of soft delete
            } else if($invoice->isForceDelete()) {
               //do in case of force delete
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For example:

```
$invoice = Invoice::find(1);
```

When $invoice is deleted (may be soft delete or force delete)

```
$invoice->delete();
$invoice->forceDelete();
```

How to determine in function boot() above the $invoice is soft deleted or force deleted ?

Comment: Doesn't `forceDelete()` perform a hard delete? IE, actually deletes the roe.

Comment: @ollieread Yes but the event is fired before that happens so the model is still available...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model has a property `forceDeleting`. Which will either be `true` or `false`:

```
if($invoice->forceDeleting){
    //do in case of force delete
}
else {
    //do in case of soft delete
}
```

**Note** that this property is only available when using the `SoftDeletingTrait`. So be careful to use this in some kind of base model.